# filter between two dates from API with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i retrieve details of an account from an `API` statement based on the user ID with the below script

```
    $http.post("http://testingserver.net/statement.php",{'id':$scope.account_number}).success
    (function(data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
$scope.statement=data;
    });
```

From the log i'm able to get the data in detail. The data from the log contains a field called `Date` which is formatted `2017-02-01T00:00:00Z` and what i want to achieve is to let the user select from two date ranges and push back the results to the user.

From the HTML below they are two fields namely `sdate` and `edate`

HTML

```
<form method="post" name="statement" id="statement">
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Search From</span>
    <input type="date" ng-model="sdate">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Search To</span>
    <input type="date" ng-model="edate">
  </label>
</div>
</form>
</br>
<div align="center">
<p><button class="button button-positive" ng-disabled="statement.$invalid" ng-click="state_request()">
  <i class="icon ion-android-search icon"></i> Search
</button></p>
</div>
```

HTML for results

```
<div ng-repeat="item in statement">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td width="70%"><div align="left">
        <p><strong> Period</strong>      </p>
      </div></td>
      <td width="82%">{{item.Date |date: 'MMMM yyyy'}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p><strong>Category</strong></p></td>
      <td>{{item.Category}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="left">
        <p><strong>Amount</strong>      </p>
      </div></td>
      <td><div align="left">{{item.Amount}}</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to format the date you might want to use [momentjs javascript time/date lib](http://momentjs.com)

It makes it incredibly easy to format and work with dates, especially concerning time inputs.

Answer (score 0):

We need to make an function for our businees logic and pass the sadte and edate: you can try for this:

```
state_request = function(sdate,edate){
    if(new Date(sadte) < new Date(edate)){
    // now write here the web service logic
    //$http.post('domain/startDate=sadte&endDate=edate'){

    }.then(function(req,res){
    //bind your html variable from here like, res.a,res.b etc
    });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to go:
1) add start/end dates and use server to do heavy lifting.
 
2) Send back all results and filter client side.

Former is probably best way to go. If you do that you'd need the dates sdate and edate in your url's query params that server would process and then have some sort of stored procedure to do date range checking. I'm not a PHP guy - Java is more my forte, and Angular 4/Ionic.